# Controller can't find DELETE route, but the method is in the controller

Tags: http-delete, sinatra-activerecord

I am building a small sinatra app but came across an issue.  My controller function for DELETE isn't being found.

ApplicationController

```
delete '/stories/:id' do
        if logged_in?
            @story = Story.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if  @story && @story.user_id == current_user.id
            params.delete("_method")
            #binding.pry
            @story.destroy
            redirect to "/users/show"
        else
            redirect to "/session/login"
        end
    end
end
```

DELETE Form Action

```
Title: <%= @story.title %><br>
Story: <%= @story.content %><br>


<form action="/stories/<%= @story.id %>" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" id="hidden"  name="_method" value="DELETE">
<input type="submit" value="Remove Story">
</form>
```

Error

```
class ApplicationController
  delete '/stories/13' do
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

I also can't pry into this route

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following middleware that will translate 
`<input type="hidden" id="hidden"  name="_method" value="DELETE">` to http `delete`

`use Rack::MethodOverride`